# Transparent TextView background in FrameLayout

Tags: android, background, textview, imageview, android-framelayout

I placed a TextView on an ImageView in a FrameLayout.  I've tried various combinations of android:background for the TextView but always get a see-through grey background on it.  I'd like a transparent background.  The android:background attribute seems to be ignored.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/categories_horizontal_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="25dip">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/categories_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/photos_imageview"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/photos_ipad" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/photos_text"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:padding="3dip" 
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="20dip" 
            />
        </FrameLayout>
              .
              .
```

Comment: If you're trying to use an image behind the text view, why not just set the image as the background of the textview? Using android:backround="@drawable/photos_ipad"

Comment: Also, try using Android's built in color for the transparent background on the Text View (android:background="@android:color/transparent")

Comment: your textview is not on the imageview...

Comment: I tried android:background="android:color/transparent", it didn't work.  The reason I am doing framelayout is I need the text to be at the bottom of the image.

Comment: Well if it didn't work, what exactly happened? It might have something to do with your scroll view. I'd make a test app that just has the frame layout and imageview/textview first. See if the transparency works. Then add the linear layout. And then the scroll view. See if you can figure out where the problem arises.

Comment: There was indeed a problem in the layout, if you post an answer I will choose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brayden pointed out, there was a problem in the layout.  I ended up putting the ImageView and TextView into a FrameLayout as a single resource, then adding that dynamically where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
TextView tv;
tv.setBackgroundColor(0xXX??????);
```

Where XX - [00;FF] - indicator of trancparecy. ?????? - Some numbers (raw color)

Hope it helped)))

Comment: You can see above that he's already setting android:background to #00000000 which is the same thing that you're suggesting, except programmatically instead of in XML.

Comment: Yeah I agree it should. But I don't think the problem lies in the setBackgroundColor call. I think it lies somewhere is his layout  hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

We use like this code for transparent background.

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```